# autohotkey array null... how do you check if the array is null/empty?

Tags: arrays, null, autohotkey

Autohotkey is a real pain something this simple is easy in C# but I cant get it to work with Autohotkey .ahk file.

`ListOfVal:=Arrays() ; Or ListOfVal:=[] | this creates the array <---comment`

I have tried this...

```
if ListOfVal=null                                  
    MsgBox, "testing"

;Ive tried all these too...

;if ListOfVal==null

;if ListOfVal:=null 

;if !ListOfVal

;if ListOfVal.MaxIndex()<1        

;if ListOfVal.MaxIndex()=-1
```

You get the idea I'm pulling hair here, help please...

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the following [MinMaxIndex](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#MinMaxIndex), [Length](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Length), [Count](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/objects/Object.htm#Count)

or [IsObject](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IsObject.htm)

Comment: Well I did get something to work... its ugly and probably the worst way to code it but here it is. Ill probably find a better way later on.

Comment: `ListOfVal:=[]


Loop{
 
GotC:=ListOfVal.GetCapacity()
 
if GetKeyState("d") 
{
ListOfVal.Insert(80)
Sleep 100
}

if GetKeyState("s") 
{
msgbox, % GotC
Sleep 100
}

}`

Comment: That code I just posted works but I did not have it looking like that. it was structured when I pasted it... I don't know why when you post something it jumbles it together like that.

Comment: Here's a better code snippet.                                                                            `global ListOfVal:=[] 

;type c to check Length ;type a to add to the length

a::
{
function(5)
} 
 
c:: 
{ 
function(0)
} 

function(x)
{
  if x>0
 {
  ListOfVal.Insert(80) 
 }else{
 GotC:=ListOfVal.Length()
 msgbox, %GotC%
 }

}`